# How to get only the associated records using Sequelize ORM Node js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have two models.
1 - Size
2 - Stock

**Size Model**

```
"use strict";
const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const Size = sequelize.define("Size", {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
});

// associations can be defined here
Size.associate = function (models) {
   // Size --> Stock
   Size.hasMany(models.Stock, { as: "sizes", foreignKey: "id" });});
 };

 return Size;
};
```

Stock Model

````
```"use strict";
const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const Stock = sequelize.define("Stock", {
    startingStock: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
     },
    total: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    sizeId: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, foreignKey: "sizeId" },
  });

// associations can be defined here
Stock.associate = function (models) {
    Stock.belongsTo(models.Size, {
        as: "sizes",
        foreignKey: "sizeId",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
     });
 };

return Stock;
};```
````

How can it get only size records that are associated to stock.
Only sizes that have relation with stocks.

````
```Size.findAll({
    include: [
      {
        model: Stock,
        as: "sizes",
        where: {
          sizeId: Sequelize.col("Size.id"),
        },
      },
    ],
 }); ```
````

I am using this query but it give me all sizes including that don't have associated record in Stock.
How can I query only those record that has associated records.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to do an inner join.
Add the required field

```
Size.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      required: true
      model: Stock,
      as: "sizes",
      where: {
        sizeId: Sequelize.col("Size.id"),
      },
    },
  ],
});
```